# 10 day quarantine when Leaving California

Tags: driving, covid-19, california, nevada, quarantine

are car travelers being asked to be '10-day quarantine' when entering California or when entering Nevada?

Comment: The title says leaving and the question says entering. Which one is it?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/10/travel/state-travel-restrictions.html) there are no road travel restrictions at all in California or Nevada, as at 16th July 2020.